# PHP array initialized inside if($_POST) block can't be used outside of it

Tags: php, arrays

I have been looking all over to find out why this is happening, but to no avail. I have a 2-step process to update specific rows (to approve timesheets) in a mySQL database based off what checkboxes are checked. In the first screen, the user checks whichever checkboxes associated with the timesheet she or he wants to update. On the next screen, I display the rows associated with those checkboxes, a confirmation page - if you will. On this confirmation page, I successfully set and echo out an array that is simply a copy of the $_POST checkbox array, called 'approvebox'. Despite this, I seemingly cannot use this array anywhere outside of the "if($_POST)" block that it is created in.

Here is the code associated with creating the first page, where the user must check the checkboxes for each timesheet she/he wishes to approve:

```
if($_POST['submit']){
...
... 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tblresults)){
            echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['timesheetsid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['unixstamp'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['total_hours'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['coordinatorid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>(<a href='./currenttimesheets.php?timesheetsid=" . $row['timesheetsid'] . "'>View</a>)</td>";
    echo "<td> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type='checkbox' name='approvebox[{$row['timesheetsid']}]' value='{$row['timesheetsid']}' /></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Here is the code in which I successfully set and echo the array that is a copy of the $_POST approvebox array. Also worth noting that I actually use the approvebox array from the if($_POST['submit']) block in a foreach loop to populate the resulting rows the user selected from the prior screen:

```
if($_POST['appove']){
...
...
foreach ($_POST['approvebox'] as $approvebox){
...
...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tblresults)){
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['timesheetsid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['unixstamp'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['total_hours'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['coordinatorid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>(<a href='./currenttimesheets.php?timesheetsid=" . $row['timesheetsid'] . "'>View</a>)</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    echo "</table>";
    print_r($_POST);
    $selectedtimesheets = array();
    $selectedtimesheets2 = array_merge($selectedtimesheets, $_POST['approvebox']);

    //$selectedtimesheets2 is successfully set to the $_POST array here
    print_r($selectedtimesheets2);
```

Finally, here is the second if($_POST) block, in which I try to use the $selectedtimesheets2 array in, but to no success, it doesn't echo out anything:

```
if($_POST['accept']){

            print_r($_POST);

            //$selectedtimesheets2 does not get echoed out, despite being successfully set and echoed previously..
            print_r($selectedtimesheets2);
            echo $selectedtimesheets2;
```

Comment: I think PHP has write protection on `$_POST` so when you add to it in braces it's only for that closure like C++ does for all variables created inside braces,

But you should not be adding stuff to post if you want to use the same store as your posted content at the top of your script you can use `$somevar = array_merge(array(), $_POST);` this prevents `$somevar` from being a pointer to `$_POST` Then use `$somevar` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: Is it possible to have `$_POST[‘accept’]`, but not `$_POST[‘approve’]`?

Comment: @MartinBarker I don't think I'm adding anything to '$_POST'... I'm trying to copy an array that is inside '$_POST' and then use that array somewhere else, outside of an if-block. I'm not sure I understand what you are saying.

Comment: @RBCunhaDesign Technically I don't need the `$_POST['approve']`, but I would want to try and solve this without taking away the `$_POST['appove']`. I'll only remove it as a last-resort. I think the confirmation step helps the user a lot.

Comment: do you know for a fact that `accept` is set in your POST? If it's not then your condition is false and it would never get inside that loop... can you echo a string within that condition to see if it even gets in there?

Comment: Are these inside different function's or files? I have sometimes seen it need more C++ like syntax try declaring `$selectedtimesheets2 = null;` before any of the closures (code inside curly braces E.G `if, while, for each ...`) happen and see if that works. If they are in different files you might need to specify global at the top of the files and if in functions you need to tell the function to use the global version with `global $selectedtimesheets2` at the top of the function body for any functions trying to use it.

Comment: @BenDubuisson Yes, `accept` is a button that is created inside the `if($_POST['approve'])` block,  as is the `$selectedtimesheets2` array. When I `print_r($selectedtimesheets2);` inside `if($_POST['approve'])`, it prints correctly. From here, I press `accept`, and inside `if($_POST['accept'])` I print both `$_POST` and `$selectedtimesheets2`. The former prints successfully, but the ladder doesn't output anything.

Comment: @MartinBarker I think you may be on to something. Initializing both `$selectedtimesheets` and `$selectedtimesheets2` at the beginning of the file finally prints something inside the `if($_POST['accept'])` block. Unfortunately, it only outputs `Array ()`. If I `var_dump($selectedtimesheets2)`, it outputs `array(0) {}`. I'm assuming this has to deal with the fact that `$_POST` populates with new values after the `accept` button is pressed. I've tried to merge `$selectedtimesheets2` with another array var that is merged with`$_POST` and an empty array, but no luck...

Comment: Sounds like two requests to me. You can’t save stuff from a previous request in memory, you’ll have to save in session or cache or db

Comment: You say ` From here, I press accept` which indicates it is a different request. Your variables are only set for the length of the php execution.

Comment: You can use PHP session to keep data between requests: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are doing two requests. Whatever was in the superglobal `_POST` after the first request won't be in the next request.

To preserve data between requests, you can use [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

You could do something like this: on first request, save that array into the session:

```
session_start();    
$_SESSION["selectedtimesheets2"] = array_merge($selectedtimesheets, 
$_POST['approvebox']);
```

Then in your next request, you can retrieve it:

```
$selectedtimesheets2 = $_SESSION["selectedtimesheets2"]
```

Does that make sense? This is very crude, I would suggest maybe using a framework  like [Symfony](https://symfony.com/), [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) or [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/), depending on size of your project. HTTP requests have been abstracted and are much easier/safer to manipulate. Also have a look at the [HTTP foundation package from Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation).

Comment: This works. For some reason, however, it doesn't like the double quotes. Using the single quotes makes this work fine. I still don't understand how I was able to pass the array of checkboxes from one if block to the next, yet not to the third. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score -1):

shouldn't `print_r($_POST);` be `print_r($_POST['approve']);`

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` would print whatever value `approve` is set to if it's there anyway. `print_r` is just used for debugging.